# Django: NOT NULL constraint failed: account_tutorvalidator.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to django and I created this "apply now form" exclusively for tutors that when they submit the form it will appear to the admin site, and I will manually check it if they are a valid tutor. And if they are a valid tutor, I will check the is_validated booleanfield in the admin site to the corresponding tutor that sent the form, so that he/she will have access to other things in the site. But I am having this problem that when you submit the form this comes up..

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: account_tutorvalidator.user_id
```

I have search for some solutions and also read similar questions here but I still couldn't understand what to do.. could someone help me out with this?

here is my models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_tutor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=True)
    current_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default-pic.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

class TutorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
related_name='tutor_profile')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'s Profile"

class TutorValidator(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(TutorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dbs = models.ImageField(upload_to='dbs_pics')
    driving_license = models.ImageField(upload_to='drivers_license_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    national_id = models.ImageField(upload_to='national_id_pics', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name}'s application form"
```

my forms.py

```
class TutorValidationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TutorValidator
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'driving_license', 'national_id']
        labels = {
        'national_id': _('National ID')
    }
```

my views.py

```
class TutorValidatorView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'account/tutor_validator.html'
    form_class = TutorValidationForm
    success_url = '/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `TutorValidator` requires that you set the user profile foreign key which your form currently does not support, so you need a way to set this to the object you are creating, and use the current logged in user (the one who is submitting the form).

You can do this by overriding `form_valid`. Try with:

```
class TutorValidatorView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        tutor_validator = form.save(commit=False)
        tutor_validator.user = self.request.user.tutor_profile 
        tutor_validator.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Note that the current user needs to already have an existing `TutorProfile`. Otherwise you need to create that first to connect it to `TutorValidator`